# Why does only one counter work when both are specified in body?

Tags: css

I'm learning about counters and I found something that I don't understand. When I make two counters and reset them both in the body, only one of them works. I don't understand why this happens and I would like a solution to this.

```css
body{
counter-reset: testA;
counter-reset: testB;
}

p::before{
counter-increment: testA;
content: counter(testA) ": ";
}


span::before{
counter-increment: testB;
content: counter(testB) ": ";
}
```

```html
<p>P one</p>

<p>P two</p>

<hr>

<span>Span one</span>

<br>
<br>

<span>Span two</span>
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It's because you are declaring two `counter-reset` on the body tag. It will automatically default to the second one. In order to have two (or more) counter-resets, use one `counter-reset` with a space separated list:

```css
body{
counter-reset: testA testB;
}

p::before{
counter-increment: testA;
content: counter(testA) ": ";
}


span::before{
counter-increment: testB;
content: counter(testB) ": ";
}
```

```html
<p>P one</p>
<p>P two</p>
<span>Span one</span>
<span>Span two</span>
```

This would happen with other CSS properties as well.

Comment: Looks like I've actually answered this before!